# Creating a global variable passed as parameter

Tags: python, dynamic, parameters, global-variables

I'm trying to create a function, that would take a parameter, then make a global variable out of it(more precisely an instance of a class).

```
class SomeClass():
    #some stuff defined inside

def create(crt, **kwargs):
    globals()[crt] = SomeClass()
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if crt.__dict__.__contains__(key):
            crt.__setattr__(key, value)
    return crt
```

Output that I'm interested in would be:

```
create(foo, class_attribute=10)
```

That would then allow me to:

```
foo.other_attribute = "whatever"
```

I can't pass a parameter without '' if it's not defined earlier, neither can I pass a string, because it's not a variable in itself, hence it can't be an instance of a class.

Would that be even possible?

Comment: You could define the global variable as None then redefine it as your class.

Comment: Think twice before using globals. Overuse of globals is a symptom of poor design. Almost any use of the global keyword is an indication of poor design. Global variables can be altered by any part of the code, making it difficult to remember or reason about every possible use.

Comment: If you want to create the variable dynamically, it has to be a string. Python doesn't allow variables to be passed by reference.

Comment: If you think you need dynamic variables, you're usually wrong. Use a dict.

Comment: Use a dict, list, or df for dynamic variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad idea, but here's how to do it.

You need to pass the name as a string. When you're setting the attributes, do it on a local variable that contains the new object.

```
def create(crt, **kwargs):
    obj = SomeClass()
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if obj.__dict__.__contains__(key):
            obj.__setattr__(key, value)
    globals()[crt] = obj
    return obj

create('foo', class_attribute=10)
foo.other_attribute = 'whatever'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing. About it being a bad idea - point is, I don't know yet how exactly will I use it, maybe I'll actually use a dict if it's really safer to do so. It was just my selfish curiosity, thank you kind Sir. ;)